# Repotting Lithops received in mail are getting wrinkled

Tags: watering

[image]

I received 8 Lithops that we’re all grown in the same pot. They came in original pot and dirt. I took them apart and repot them and the 3 Dorthea Lithops are the ones that are getting wrinkled. The other ones are fine and seem to be doing good. Is this normal for that type of Lithop this time of year? Should I put them in their own pot?

Thank you!
Celina

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrinkled in the image. Is there a particular plant you can point to?

That said, when repotting succulents they can lose some moisture temporarily and appear wrinkled. Keep them away from excessive heat and light for a few day and water very sparingly. If you didn't let the roots dry between removing them from the old pot and planting them in the new pot, don't water for a week at least.

You don't mention where on the globe you are (it matters in this case). Lightops flower in the fall/winter and shouldn't get any water between flowering and new leaves appearing.

What was the motivation to repot? Did you use cactus/succulent soil or standard peat-based potting soil?